# Elastic beanstalk - eb create fails to create AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I currently want to deploy a simple Django app in AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and RDS, following this tutorial: http://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/05/23/tutorial-django-elastic-beanstalk/. To create the Beanstalk app I use the command `eb create --scale 1 -db -db.engine postgres -db.i db.t2.micro`.

In the creation process, the tool fails to create the [AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup]. Here is the output:

```
2018-07-28 06:07:51    ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-ygq5xuvccr-stack' aborted 
operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) 
failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup].
2018-07-28 06:07:51    ERROR   Creating RDS database security group named: 
awseb-e-ygq5xuvccr-stack-awsebrdsdbsecuritygroup-oj71kkwnaaag failed Reason: 
Either the resource does not exist, or you do not have the required permissions.
```

I am using an access token with full administrator rights.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you maxed out? Try deleting an unused security group or requesting more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a DB Security group and not a VPC Security group? AFAIK, db security groups should no longer be needed in new accounts, you should just be able to attach an existing VPC security group directly to your instance.

If you do need it, then its most likely one of these:

1. A badly worded error for hitting the limits for max db security groups
2. You actually don't have the admin permissions as you claimed.

Do try out and let us know what you find.